# Realm fetch returning wrong results

Tags: objective-c, realm

I've got two RLMObject subclasses: Habit, and Doable. Doables have a 'habit' property (so each Doable can have a single Habit, but multiple Doables can belong to the same Habit). Habits have a primary key 'id' field that is a GUID.

I'm trying to look up Doables based on a particular habit:

```
NSLog(@"habit.id: %@", habit.id)
// habit.id: 03736F78-BA78-4E43-B6E5-693D369D0E3D

RLMResults<Doable*>* doables = [Doable objectsWhere:@"habit = %@", habit];
```

But when I look at the returned results, the Doables returned are for a different habit:

```
for (Doable* doable in doables) {
  NSLog(@"doable.habit.id: %@", doable.habit.id);
}

// doable.habit.id: 4DFD946A-8F56-4F21-9987-7B2DFC8B66DF
// doable.habit.id: 4DFD946A-8F56-4F21-9987-7B2DFC8B66DF
// doable.habit.id: 4DFD946A-8F56-4F21-9987-7B2DFC8B66DF
```

Any idea what's going on here? I'm running Realm 0.95.2

Thanks!

Comment: Do you query with a new `Habit` object or is it already added to the Realm?

Comment: The Habit object was in the Realm at the time of querying, but it had only just been added (the code in my question is called immediately after adding the habit to the realm and commiting).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be due to the [issue described here](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/pull/2650).

As a workaround for now, I would propose to use your `id` property, assuming that it is suitable to identify objects:

```
RLMResults<Doable*>* doables = [Doable objectsWhere:@"habit.id = %@", habit.id];
```

Comment: The issue described there fits what's happening for me. Nice find. Querying by id does successfully work around the issue for now. Thanks!